# jQuery first element of type click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working through an issue where I have a menu that is mutli levels deep. I am trying to get it so that if a first level element is clicked (add class `.ubermenu-active`) it will look for any other first level element with that class and remove it.

```
$('.ubermenu-item-level-0 span').on('click',function() {
    var target = $('.ubermenu-item-level-0');
    $('.ubermenu li.ubermenu-item-level-0').removeClass('ubermenu-active');
    target.parents('.ubermenu li.ubermenu-item-level-0').toggleClass('ubermenu-active');
});
```

HTML (mock):

```
<ul class="ubermenu">
    <li class="ubermenu-item-level-0">
        <a class="ubermenu-target">
            <span class="ubermenu-target-title">Level 1</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="ubermenu-submenu">
            <li class="ubermenu-item-level-1">
                <a class="ubermenu-target">
                    <span class="ubermenu-target-title">Level 2</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="ubermenu-item-level-1">
                <a class="ubermenu-target">
                    <span class="ubermenu-target-title">Level 2</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="ubermenu-submenu">
                    <li class="ubermenu-item-level-2">
                        <a class="ubermenu-target">
                            <span class="ubermenu-target-title">Level 3</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li class="ubermenu-item-level-0">
            <a class="ubermenu-target">
                <span class="ubermenu-target-title">Level 1</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Right now if any of the sub elements are clicked the parent closes

Comment: I think I know what you are looking for, but seeing the actual HTML would help make sure that the DOM structure is clear.

Comment: I can try and create a clean version of the menus to give you an idea. Ubermenu just puts a TON of bloat in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your sample HTML isn't what I expected to see . . . specifically, your second `<li class="ubermenu-item-level-0" . . .` element is currently showing as a child under the first one, while your description makes it sound like they should be siblings.

For the sake of the solution I'm going to assume that those two `li`s are supposed to be siblings of each other and that somehow the code got mixed up.   :)

So, here's how I would handle it . . .

```
var sFirstLevelMenuClass = ".ubermenu-item-level-0";
var sActiveMenuClass = "ubermenu-active";
var $firstLevelMenuOptions = $(".ubermenu").find(sFirstLevelMenuClass);

$firstLevelMenuOptions.children("a").children("span").on("click", function() {
    $firstLevelMenuOptions.removeClass(sActiveMenuClass);
    $(this).closest(sFirstLevelMenuClass).addClass(sActiveMenuClass);
});
```

Basically, I've simplified your logic and fixed one small issue that you had in your jQuery code.

---

**Detailed Explanation**

The issue was that when you used `$('.ubermenu-item-level-0 span')` as your selector for your change event.  That translates to "any `span` element that is a descendant of a `ubermenu-item-level-0` element".  So, in addition to the spans that are directly under the `ubermenu-item-level-0` list items, it was also picking up the ones under the `ubermenu-item-level-1` and `ubermenu-item-level-2` elements, since they are also descendants.

So, I changed your selector to `$firstLevelMenuOptions.children("a").children("span")` which translates to "all `span`s, that are direct children of an `a`, that is the direct child of an `ubermenu-item-level-0` element" (*Note: `$firstLevelMenuOptions` is set to equal `$(".ubermenu").find(".ubermenu-active");` through the logic earlier in the code*).  This stops the selector from picking up the lower level `spans`.

Outside of that and trimming down some of your selectors to be more efficient, the only other thing that I changed was the flow of how the `ubermenu-active` class is manipulated.  In my solution, there are two steps:

1. Remove `ubermenu-active` from **ALL** `ubermenu-item-level-0` elements
2. Add `ubermenu-active` to the closest `ubermenu-item-level-0` element to the `span` that was clicked (i.e., `$(this)`)

That basically resets the list and then reselects the appropriate menu item to me active.

Comment: This worked very well and was a great explanation. Thank you very very much.

Comment: Happy it helped.   :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently your `target` var is selecting all elements with class `.ubermenu-item-level-0`, so when you toggle the class you're toggling all parent elements. Your target var should be something relative to the element clicked, like `var target = $(this).closest('.ubermenu-item-level-0');`

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the event propagation:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full HTML, I was going to suggest trying this:

```
$('.ubermenu-item-level-0 span').on('click',function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       var target = $('.ubermenu-item-level-0');
       $('.ubermenu li.ubermenu-item-level-0').removeClass('ubermenu-active');
       target.parents('.ubermenu li.ubermenu-item-level-0').toggleClass('ubermenu-active');
    });
```

Comment: e.stopPropagation(); seems to break the menu. IE: it won't drop down any submenus now.

Comment: @RyleyAmeden, I think we will need to see some HTML/CSS to help you further.